# SQL Lookup T1.ColumnA vs T2.ColumnA, if all 5 values in T1.ColumnA are listed in T2.ColumnA, Replace T1.ColumnA with "ALL"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to perform a lookup of specific values. If all values for Table1 for Region are listed as part of the lookup table (Table2), then replace the Table1.Region field with value = 'ALL', basically trying to group all 5 regions and subsitute the value with "ALL" when all 5 regions are listed (according to the values in the lookup table) When all regions ARE NOT listed, keep the Region Code

```
Year   Region   Value
2012    A1      24
2012    B2      24
2012    C3      24
2012    D4      24
2012    E5      24
2012    A1      36
2012    B2      36
2012    C3      36
2012    D4      36
2012    E5      36
2013    A1      24
2013    B2      24


Lookup Table
Region  Value
1         A1
2         B2
3         C3
4         D4
5         E5
```

Result Desired

```
Year    Region Term
2012    ALL    24   <-- Note region change to all because there are 5 regions per above 
2012    ALL    36   <-- Note region change to all because there are 5 regions per above
2013    A1     24   <-- Region did not change because there were only 2 regions in source
2013    B2     24   <-- Region did not change because there were only 2 regions in source
```

I know how to group data but the grouped data needs to be consolidated further and replaced with ALL

Thanks for any direction!

Carlos

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using SSMS 2008, just wanting to do it via SQL query. I have multiple lookups to combine to ALL

Answer (score 0):

There's a little trick to this:

(@var IS NULL OR Table1.Region = @var)

you need to translate 'ALL' to null, so when 'ALL' is selected, it cancels out the filter.

I'd imagine you're either using SSRS, or a drop down above this, but here's a link:

https://www.simple-talk.com/content/print.aspx?article=835#hr2

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify what RDBMS you are using but you should be able to use the following in all database products:

```
select distinct t1.year,
  case 
    when t2.year is null and t2.value is null
    then t1.region
    else 'ALL' End Region,
  t1.value
from table1 t1
left join
(
  select year, value
  from table1
  group by year, value
  having count(distinct region) = (select count(distinct value)
                                   from table2)
) t2
  on t1.year = t2.year
  and t1.value = t2.value
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/66992/14)

Answer (score 0):

Use this query with [APPLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) AND [EXCEPT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) operators

```
SELECT t1.Year, CASE WHEN o.Value IS NULL THEN 'ALL' ELSE t1.Region END AS Region,
       t1.Value
FROM dbo.test7 t1 OUTER APPLY (                               
                               SELECT Value
                               FROM test8 
                               EXCEPT                               
                               SELECT Region
                               FROM test7 t2
                               WHERE t1.Year = t2.Year
                                 AND t1.Value = t2.Value                                                             
                               ) o
GROUP BY t1.Year, CASE WHEN o.Value IS NULL THEN 'ALL' ELSE t1.Region END, 
         t1.Value
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/71729/1)